# Armstrong number using prolog

Tags: prolog

Can Someone help me with the code for "finding if a no is armstrong no or not using prolog programming"?
I can't seem to find a solution anywhere.

Comment: I recommend adding an intro to explain the Armstrong Number: [Narcissistic Number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Narcissistic_number). This is a good occasion to add code to [Rosetta Code](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Narcissistic_decimal_number) which has no solution yet.

Comment: for any base or for a fixed base?

Answer (score 2):

Narcissistic numbers have different aliases such as Armstrong number, pluperfect digital invariant (PPDI) or plus perfect number.

```
numberToDigitsR(N,_,[]):-
    N < 0, !.
numberToDigitsR(N,B,[N]):-
    N < B, !.
numberToDigitsR(N,B,[Mod|R]):-
    Mod is N mod B,
    Div is N div B,
    numberToDigitsR(Div,B,R).

powerList([],_,0).
powerList([H|T],E,Sum):-
    powerList(T,E,TT),
    Sum is (H**E)+TT.

narcissist(N,B):-
    B>1,
    numberToDigitsR(N,B,D),
    length(D,E),
    powerList(D,E,N).
```

tests:

```
?- narcissist(54748,10).
true.

?- narcissist(54748,9).
false.

?- narcissist(62,4).
true.

?- member(B,[2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16]), narcissist(54748,B).
B = 10 ;
false.
```

Thanks David for linking the wiki site.

The program first creates a list of the "digits" for a given number `N` and a given base `B`. Then it calculates the number of digits `E` and calculates the sum of each digit to the power of `E`. If the output equals the number `N` then this is a narcissistic number. If the base `B` is not known before, simply state the domain as shown in the last example.
Please note that this algorithm does not work for `B=1`.
Also note that the number `N` is given with *decimal* format. So if you look up numbers from [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20100109234250/http://ftp.cwi.nl/dik/Armstrong) website, please convert the numbers to base 10 first.

Comment: If you want more people to find your answer then you the name `Narcissistic number`

Comment: @GuyCoder Thanks for the hint. The german wikipedia site somewhat implies that armstrong numbers are a subcathegory of narcissistic numbers so I concluded I would be on the safe side to use the term armstrong number.

Comment: Use both. The purpose of writing an answer is for it to be found. So make it easy for others to find it. Sometimes I will even just add a section of keywords in an answer or question for just that purpose.